# Linked List in C not printing the last value

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to implement Linked List in C, where i'm inserting the nodes at the end of the list, after I insert values, all values except the last value is printing. Here is the code:

```
list_t *add(list_t *l,int e)
{
list_t *head;

if(l == NULL)
{
    l = malloc(sizeof(list_t));
    l->val = e;
    l->next = NULL;
    return l;
}       

head = l;

while(l->next != NULL)
    l=l->next;

l->next = malloc(sizeof(list_t));
l=l->next;
l->val = e;
l->next = NULL;

return head;
}
```

And here is the implementation of the main function:

```
int main()
{
list_t *ints=NULL;
list_t *temp;
int i, choice;

while(1){
 printf("1. Enter\n2. Show List\n3. Exit\n\n");
 scanf("%d", &choice);
 switch(choice){
    case 1:
        printf("Enter item\n");
        scanf("%d", &i);
        ints = add(ints,i);
        break;
    case 2:
        temp = ints;
        while(temp->next != NULL)
        {   
            printf("%d\n",temp->val);
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        break;
    case 3:
    default:
        exit(0);

    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Time to learn how to **use the debugger**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
while(temp->next != NULL)
```

explicitly says "stop when you get to the element that points to end-of-list" (i.e stop when you get to the last element but before you use it).

Instead use

```
while(temp != NULL)
```

which says "stop when you are no-longer in the list".

Comment: Don't help the vampires, man.

Comment: Ouch :D
Well, I realized how much of a mess that question was, and That's when I started learning using a debugger(gdb) and learning data structures along with gdb is a bit of hassle though but in the end of the day its all worth learning the debugger. I can now merge sort a linked list, and fix errors by myself(for the most part) instead of asking it here in stackoverflow :) :)

Comment: Struck me as a more genuine request for assistance than the large number of "here's my homework, do it for me" questions SO was full of this weekend. gdb is a bear to learn but can be a fantastic tool. If you're running a modern GDB there is a command line option for a text-based ui: `gdb -tui`, e.g. if you're debugging 'foo.exe' `gdb -tui foo.exe`. Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, and also the tip using GDB, I'll try that out :)

Answer (score 0):

In your case 2, in your main function, you go out of the while loop as soon as there is no next element anymore.
But because this is your last element, it doesn't get displayed.
Add another print after your loop to print the last element that the loop doesn't contain.

```
    while(temp->next != NULL)
    {   
        printf("%d\n",temp->val);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    break;
```

becomes

```
    while(temp->next != NULL)
    {   
        printf("%d\n",temp->val);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    printf("%d\n",temp->val);
    break;
```

or better:

```
    while(temp!= NULL)
    {   
        printf("%d\n",temp->val);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    break;
```